# How to calculate based on different levels of a hierarchy - Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, hierarchy, standard-deviation, measure

Take the following matrix;

[image: matrix]

I need to know how to perform calculations on different levels of a hierarchy.

Say the Customer Service is Level2 of the hierarchy. (Level 1 being client)

The **STDEVP.1_Duration** is the Standard deviation measure on the duration column values. So as per the image above I need to add a new column beside it where it takes the **Duration** and subtracts the **STDEVP.1_duration** of the level above. So in the example above for Customer Service, Total = 22194891 - 406 = 22194485.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You might be able to adapt this to your need:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/data-adventures/2017/04/30/dax-calculations-with-hierarchies-set-the-order-straight/

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following DAX based on the link recommended by Ryan.B

```
  IF (
  ISFILTERED ( AgentTable[EmployeeID] ),
  CALCULATE([STDEVP.1_Duration],ALL(AgentTable[EmployeeID])) - SUM(Duration),
     IF (
        ISFILTERED ( AgentTable[TeamID] ),
        CALCULATE([STDEVP.1_Duration],ALL(AgentTable[TeamID]))- SUM(Duration),
             IF (
                 ISFILTERED ( AgentTable[DeptID] ),
                 CALCULATE([STDEVP.1_Duration],ALL(AgentTable[DeptID]))- SUM(Duration),
                     IF (
                        ISFILTERED ( AgentTable[ClientID]),
                        CALCULATE([STDEVP.1_Duration],ALL(AgentTable[ClientID]))- SUM(Duration)

        )
    )
)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Yes basically we use ISFILTERED for such requirements.
However, sometimes your total line might be wrong or empty, in that case you can add HASONEFILTER to detect total line and calucte it differently
Also you might need to have different number formats for each level, in that case you can add FORMAT function. Yet because it is a text function you might have empty lines, so you need to add ISBLANK.

The code below solves them all :
It calculates the production in region level (region has several contries) and % of region in country level:

Measure =

IF(NOT(HASONEFILTER(Hierarchy[region])),[production],

IF(NOT(ISBLANK([production])),
IF(ISFILTERED(Hierarchy[region])&&NOT(ISFILTERED(Hierarchy[country])),[production],

IF(ISFILTERED(Hierarchy[country]),FORMAT(DIVIDE([production],CALCULATE([production],ALL(Hierarchy[country]))),"Percent")))))

This video also explains calculation based on hierarchy with the example :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LV9LqcEmgFc